# Access to SharedPreferences from different activity

Tags: android

In first (MainActivity) I save data trough SharedPreferences:

```
Editor editor = mGameSettings.edit(); 
                editor.putString(GAME_PREFERENCES_SHOP, Shops.get(lv.getCheckedItemPosition())); 
                editor.commit();
```

And I can read this data from MainActivity after restart application:

```
if (mGameSettings.contains(GAME_PREFERENCES_SHOP)) 

                Tv2.setText(mGameSettings.getString(GAME_PREFERENCES_SHOP, ""));
```

But how to read and edit this SharedPreferences from other activity?

Comment: with the same code, just be sure to use the same name "GAME_PREFERENCES_SHOP", you can edit it from any activity, even from an alarm or a service with your code

Comment: Are you seeing this not working on other Activities? Are the other activities in other applications? If it's the same app, the code you posted should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write the Below code in your another activity:

```
SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
if (sp.contains(MainActivity.GAME_PREFERENCES_SHOP)) //hoping that GAME_PREFERENCES_SHOP is a static constant defined in MainActivity
                Tv2.setText(sp.getString(MainActivity.GAME_PREFERENCES_SHOP, ""));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code for getting the preference value from different Application

```
    Context launcherContext = null;
    try {
        final int flags = Context.CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY | Context.CONTEXT_INCLUDE_CODE;
        launcherContext = getApplicationContext().createPackageContext("com.another.package", flags);
    } catch (final NameNotFoundException e) {
        return ;
    }

    final SharedPreferences pref = launcherContext.getSharedPreferences(
            "prefname",
            Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE | Context.MODE_MULTI_PROCESS);

    final String prefValue = pref.getString("prefname", null);
    Log.i("test", prefValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read and edit with the `same code`. You just have to use the same Prefs file name and `key` for the required value. 
You can declare your Pref File name as `public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";` in the main activity and then access it from anywhere in the application.

Example, in other Activity:

```
    SharedPreferences mGameSettings = getSharedPreferences(MainActivity.PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
    if (mGameSettings.contains(MainActivity.GAME_PREFERENCES_SHOP)) 
        Tv2.setText(mGameSettings.getString(MainActivity.GAME_PREFERENCES_SHOP, ""));
```